# How to customize collection rendering when using active_model_serializers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ember-data

I am using active_model_serializers to render a collection as JSON for ember-data consumption.
All is ok when rendering a single item, but collection rendering consists as an array of items.

```
render json: @scenarios, status: :ok
```

gives:

```
[{"scenario":{"id":4,"name":"My sample scenario"}},{"scenario":{"id":5,"name":"Yet another sample scenario"}}]
```

but I would like to obtain:

```
{"scenarios": [{"id":4,"name":"My sample scenario"},{"id":5,"name":"Yet another sample scenario"}]}
```

What is the state of the art way to get a root key with all collection items, side-data, and so on? (the documentation is not that clear about this)

**EDIT**

The scenario serializer is currently as follow:

```
class ScenarioSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name
end
```

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/322-rabl

Comment: @jdoe Thanks for your suggestion, but I would like to keep using active_model_serializers as I don't want to have code myself all the serialization concerns.

Comment: What does your scenario_serializer.rb (or equivalent) look like?

Comment: @pansapien Just updated the question...

Comment: Does 'embed :ids' make any difference? I'm getting the JSON formatted as you desire yours to be, but that's the only difference I have with my code. It's not clear to me that it should make a difference, but would be something to try.

Comment: @pansapien Thks again for your time, but it does not work for me. :-( 
Certainly something somewhere has to be different...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the latest version. AMS uses the controller name as the key for an array. By default it should render like you showed above.

If your controller is not named ScenariosController, you can force the root element of the array like this:

```
render json: @scenarios, root: "scenarios", status: :ok
```

Comment: That's right. In fact, I had a mistake elsewhere... some of my model classes had a custom `to_json` implementation which I missed... :-(

Comment: Cool. In general, there is better handling of arrays in AMS now.